# How can I connect my Custom-built PC with portable monitory Lenovo ThinkVision M14t which has only USB-C (alt mode)?

Tags: usb, display, multiple-monitors, external-display, usb-c

I am thinking of buying a portable screen with stylus support for note-taking. I have narrowed my choice to a couple of monitors, the primary one being **Lenovo ThinkVision M14t.** I liked its design and want to use it with my PC, but the specification shows that it only has **a USB-C port (in alt mode)** through which it gets both display signal and power from the device it is hooked to.

I wonder if I can connect my 4-5 years old custom-built PC, which has **Asus Maximus VIII Hero** motherboard and **2GB DDR5 Asus GTX960 Black OC Edition GTX960-DC2OC-2GD5** Graphics card.

Links:

Lenovo ThinkVision M14t: [Lenovo ThinkVision M14t](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/accessories-and-monitors/monitors/office/M14tA20140FX014inch-Monitor/p/62A3UAR1US)

Motherboard: [Asus Maximus VIII Hero](https://www.asus.com/in/Motherboards/MAXIMUS-VIII-HERO/)

Graphic Card:  [2GB DDR5 Asus GTX960 Black OC Edition](https://www.asus.com/in/Graphics-Cards/STRIXGTX960DC2OC2GD5/)

Answer (score 1):

To get video over Type-C port on a system that does not have the Alt-DP over USB-C supported, you will need to install an adapter that combines USB with DisplayPort data stream. [Here is one](http://www.sunix.com/en/product_detail.php?pid=1909):

[image]

You will need a short DP cable to connect your videocard output to this adapter. Then the adapter's USB-C port will provide you with ALT-DP mode for your TYPE-C portable monitor.
[image]